# Implementing "Like" functionality

Tags: sql, nosql, sql-like

I need to create an application which has "likes" in it. It means that a person with a *unique ID* can like an item with a *unique ID*, but only *once*. The item *cannot* be disliked.  I have only came up with a little table, which has the `user_id` and `item_id` columns, before inserting I should check whether this user has already liked the item. It seems to me that this is not the best way to accomplish the task, because there is going to be a lot of (~1 million) users and a lot of items, so the table should be pretty large and that will affect the search and insertion speed. Is there any other approach to do this? Or if my method is suitable here, what is the best method of storing this information in the database? Currently I am using MySQL database, is it better to use NoSql here?

Comment: Define a unique index on (user_id,item_id) to impose your constraint. This is more set-based thatn hierarchical, so SQL is fine as an implementation choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first thing to do is set a "unique" constraint on the TWO columns (combined) so that their combination is unique. Not sure if MySQL supports this, but MSSQL express sure does, and you can have up to 8 GB of data, so a million users is not getting even close to its limit -- scales well if you have well more than a million. You should create a covering index on liker and liked and make it unique. With a 80 padding insert are going to be instant and so are lookups. This is a relational problem so a relational database will cream any non relational (NO SQL) database for speed and efficiency. you didnt mention if liker and liked were comutive - I guess not